# Add new columns to a dataframe and rename them accordingly based on shiny widget selections

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I want the user to select 1 to 3 choices from the input and then add the relevant vectors to the existing dataframe `graph1.data` as new columns.

For example if he selects all 3 choices he should have a dataframe with 6 new columns. But instead of the vector names these columns should be named in that case `x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2` regardless of which choice is selected first. For example if `Gross Sales` is selected first then `GrossSalesx2` should be the `x` and `GrossSalesy2` should be the `y`.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
BRAND<-c("CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","LARA CHOCO CHIPS","LARA CHOCO CHIPS","LARA CHOCO CHIPS")
BRAND_COLOR<-c("#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#f050c0","#f050c0","#f050c0")

SellOut.x<-c(23,34,56,77,78,34,34,64,76)
SellOut.y<-c(43,54,76,78,87,98,76,76,56)
GrossProfit.x1<-c(23,34,56,75,78,34,34,64,76)
GrossProfit.y1<-c(33,54,76,76,87,98,76,76,56)
GrossSales.x2<-c(53,34,56,77,78,34,34,84,76)
GrossSales.y2<-c(63,54,76,78,87,98,76,76,86)
r<-c(58,46,76,76,54,21,69,98,98)


graph1.data<-data.frame(BRAND,r)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("metric","Metric",c('Gross Sales','Gross Profit','Sell Out'),multiple = T,selected = "Sell Out")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    DTOutput("df")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$df<-renderDT({})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following one:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
BRAND<-c("CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","CHOKIS","LARA CHOCO CHIPS","LARA CHOCO CHIPS","LARA CHOCO CHIPS")
BRAND_COLOR<-c("#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#8050f0","#f050c0","#f050c0","#f050c0")

SellOut.x<-c(23,34,56,77,78,34,34,64,76)
SellOut.y<-c(43,54,76,78,87,98,76,76,56)
GrossProfit.x1<-c(23,34,56,75,78,34,34,64,76)
GrossProfit.y1<-c(33,54,76,76,87,98,76,76,56)
GrossSales.x2<-c(53,34,56,77,78,34,34,84,76)
GrossSales.y2<-c(63,54,76,78,87,98,76,76,86)
r<-c(58,46,76,76,54,21,69,98,98)

graph1.data<-data.frame(BRAND,r)

# data frame containing columns to be added
df6 <- data.frame(SellOut.x, SellOut.y, GrossProfit.x1, GrossProfit.y1, GrossSales.x2, GrossSales.y2) 

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("metric","Metric",c('Gross Sales','Gross Profit','Sell Out'),multiple = T,selected = "Sell Out")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    verbatimTextOutput("selections"), # optional
    DTOutput("df")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  

  
  choices <- reactive({
   c3 <- gsub(" ", "", input$metric) # remove space
   
   return(c3)
  })
  
  reactiveDf <- reactive({
    if(length(choices()) > 0){
      # if choices match column names of df6
      g1 <- apply(sapply(X = choices(), FUN = grepl, colnames(df6)), MARGIN =  1, FUN = any)
      
      addedDf <- df6[, g1] # columns to be added
      colnames(addedDf) <- c("x", "y", "x1", "y1", "x2", "y2")[1:ncol(addedDf)] # change column names
      
      combinedDf <- cbind(graph1.data, addedDf) # add columns
      return(combinedDf)
    }else{
      return(graph1.data) 
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$selections<- renderPrint({
    choices()
  })
  
  output$df<-renderDT({
    reactiveDf()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: in the right direction but the colnames of the dataframe should follow this logic. The first 2 should always be named "x","y" -the second 2 "x1","y1" and the third 2 "x2","y2" regardless of the order that the inputs from the widget will be selected.

Comment: Then you only need to change the names of the added columns. See the modified code.

Comment: follow up Q based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476053/processing-a-reactive-dataframe-gives-invalid-null-left-side-of-assignment-err